# How can I escape whitespace in my shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, escaping

I got this script to easily send files to my server:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp $1 user@host:/home/user/dir
```

I saved the script in */usr/local/bin* by name *send2server* and start it like this:

`~$ send2server filename`

Now the problem is, if there is whitespace in the filename, the script will not escape it with \

So, how can I put \ in front of the whitespace into my script in the variable $1?

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions are bugs until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Quote variable expansions to protect them from undesirable globbing and word splitting. This should be your default: it's rare to purposefully need to leave an expansion unquoted.

```
scp "$1" user@host:/home/user/dir
```